# Geometry nodes dont update real time in python script

Tags: python, scripting, geometry-nodes

I have created an object using geometry nodes. I control its input node "String."
I want to control the position of this object based on the x dimension, but when I change the string (therefore, the dimensions of the object), it does not update immediately. Instead, it keeps the location of the previous string, and only when I rerun the script again, the object moves to the correct position.

```
import bpy

Texts = bpy.data.collections["Texts"].objects

bpy.data.node_groups["Geometry Nodes"].nodes["String"].string = 'The Text I Want To Change'

Texts[0].location[0] = 0 - Texts[0].dimensions.x/2
```

[image: My Geometry nodes]

[image: gif]

Comment: This works immediately for me. What Blender version are you using? I'm on 3.3.0

Comment: I use 3.3.1, so it should not be a problem. Have you also tried to change the string after the first use? I edited the question, so my problem is more clear.

Comment: try `bpy.context.view_layer.update()`

Comment: I tried it many times, was kinda fun to play with :) Can you share your .blend please. Edit your question with the link it makes https://blend-exchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Markus von Broady

```
bpy.context.view_layer.update()
```

This did the trick!